# Timestamp to timestamp with timezone

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have to compare the value in column that has datatype as timestamp with that of column that has timestamp with timezone datatype. please tell me how can i convert the former datatype to timestamp with timezone. I have query something like :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1>= (SELECT COL2 FROM TABLE 2)
```

Where COL1 is TIMESTAMP and COL2 is TIMESTAMP WITH TZ

The sample value i  COL2 is  : 15-JUN-12 05.46.29.600102000 PM -07:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CAST(COL1 as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)`

Oracle takes current user session time zone `SESSIONTIMEZONE` into account for conversion. Comparison itself is done always on UTC values.

If you like to specify time zone you can [FROM_TZ](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions077.htm#SQLRF00644), for example `FROM_TZ(COL1, 'Europe/Zurich')`